# How to solve expects parameter issue with mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I am getting this error in `script1.php`.

This is what I have tried so far. Below is my `script1.php` code after that it goes to `welcome.php`:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "demo");
echo "jay";

// Check connection
if ($link === false)
{
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    session_start();
}

$uname1 = ($_POST['username']);
$pass1 = ($_POST['password']);

$sql = "SELECT id FROM persons WHERE usernamesignup = '$uname1' and passwordsignup= '$pass1'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$active = $row['active'];

$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if ($count == 1)
{
    echo " jayesh vyas";
    session_register("myusername");
    $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;

    header("location: welcome.php");
} else
{
    $error = "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
}
?>
```

`welcome.php` code is as follows:

```
<?php
include('session.php');
?>
<html">

<head>
    <title>Welcome </title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Welcome <?php echo $login_session; ?></h1>
<h2><a href="logout.php">Sign Out</a></h2>
</body>

</html>
```

So whenever I execute the `script1.php` it shows me some warnings as follows:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\LoginRegistrationForm\script1.php on
>   line 17
>
> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\LoginRegistrationForm\script1.php on
>   line 20

I appreciate to learn what I have done wrong and solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysqli_query` will return `false` on error as opposed to a `resource`, similar to `mysqli_connect`.

> Returns **FALSE** on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return **TRUE**.

To resolve the issue,  wrap your `mysqli_query` in an `if` conditional to ensure no errors have occurred, and output the errors in your development environment.

Since your query is accepting user input, I also suggest using a prepared statement, to help reduce the risk of SQL Injection.

```
$sql = 'SELECT `id` FROM `persons` WHERE `usernamesignup` = ? AND `passwordsignup` = ?';
if (!$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)) {
    die(mysqli_error($link));
}
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $uname1, $pass1);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id);
mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

echo $id;

mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
mysqli_close($link);
```

---

As a side note, you should also move your `session_start();` out of the `if ($link === FALSE)` block.